# Internet wired connection holds only few seconds/few requests before needing to call dhclient again

Tags: networking, dns, wired, dhclient

I have a dual boot ubuntu/windows 8, everything was working fine, suddently, after a reboot from the linux partition, the DNS resolution seems to be in trouble : I have to run dhclient before each internet request I do. One exception : if I stay in the google search, it always works, until I go to a website, then connection drops and I have to call dhclient again.
So I guess that each time it tries to resolve an address, it @forget@ about the DNS path, maybe.

This also affects my windows partition, I have to change the dns every time I do an internet access. So I think that linux messed things up with my ethernet device.

Here is my interface file :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

My ifconfig output :

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:9e:17:01:cd:a0  
          inet addr:85.227.x.y  Bcast:85.227.x.y  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ae9e:17ff:fe01:cda0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13313 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12057 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11890102 (11.8 MB)  TX bytes:2143283 (2.1 MB)
          Interrupt:47 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:10566
```

Comment: If you have to run `dhclient` often, then it sounds like your DHCP server is forgetting the IP address assignment or some other problem.  Does this happen on other networks as well?

Comment: well, not with the wifi access, I have no trouble with it. For others ethernet networks I can't test

Comment: Well if Windows is also affected then I'd point at Ethernet hardware problems potentially.

Comment: After switching to my other hardrive, I don't have the problem on it. So there is something coming from linux, I am sure !

Comment: Did you verify that you have the correct drivers installed for the wifi?

Comment: I finally solved it, I've edited my post !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was an ssd that was not the main hard drive of my computer, I've put back the main hardrive, the connection was then working, so when I came back to the ssd it was working again !